# Display only one generic message instead of one per input

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, parsley.js

Is there any way to display only one generic error message, at the bottom of the form, for ex. "Please check the required fields" instead of one message per input inside a [Parsley](http://parsleyjs.org/) form?

I'm looking at the docs but I don't find any options for this.

Comment: how do you want to achieve this using Parsley liberary or default jquery form validator?

Comment: I would like to achive this using only Parsley.js. If possible with the data-atributes API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no option for this per say.

If you only use the `required` check, you could simply hide in CSS the parsley error messages and use the `validated`/`error` events on the form to hide/display your generic error message.

Comment: Tks Marc seems one possible solution, though, I was looking for something out of the box using the data atributes API.

Comment: As I said, there's no built-in option for this, sorry.

Comment: Ok. If we use the default messages for each input, Wen the user changes the value the message is automatically hidden. Is it it possible do something like this via JS with the events API ? @marc-andré-lafortune

Comment: Not sure I understand. If this is a different question, ask a new one! Otherwise, expand your original question.

Comment: You're right. I'll put another question if necessary.